# PHP ffmpeg exec returns null

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I'm trying to run ffmpeg through a PHP exec call, I've been debugging for a while and looked at lot of responses on here, but still not found any answers...

My simplified call is:

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg 2>&1';

exec(escapeshellcmd($cmd), $stdout, $stderr);

var_dump($stderr);
var_dump($stdout);
var_dump($cmd);
exit;
```

My output is $stderr = int(1) and $stdout = array(0) { }

Also I tried `shell_exec($cmd)` which returns `NULL`.

cmd.exe has permissions set for the IUSR account - e.g. I can run `$cmd = 'dir'` and see a directory listing output.

PHP is not running in safe mode.

The ffmpeg.exe is in the same directory as my php file, but I have the same response giving an absolute path to the ffmpeg.exe file in `$cmd`.

ffmpeg is executing fine from the command line.

I'm running Windows XP, IIS and PHP 5.3.

EDIT:

If I run 'ffmpeg -h' I get the help commands, which must indicated that ffmpeg is recognised

I've increased the PHP memory limit to 1024 - no luck.

Comment: The second parameter to exec() is the `return value`, not `stderr`. A return value of 1 implies that it errored. I have no idea why you don't see the error output in $stdout though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've now got this working - I think there may have been several issues:

It turns out that `$cmd = 'ffmpeg'` returns null, so it's not a good test!

Also running escape shell command on '2>&1' echoes 2^>^&1" - I think this was my original problem.

I've now managed to rea test file using: 'ffmpeg -i SAMPLE.AVI 2>&1'.

Working code:

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i SAMPLE.AVI 2>&1';

exec($cmd, $output, $value);

var_dump($output);
var_dump($value);
var_dump($cmd);
exit;
```

As noted above ffmpeg is a bit of a memory hog, so it's worth checking memory too.

Comment: So in other words, ffmpeg only writes to the stderr instead of the stdout?

Comment: the command does not return null, it will list out the configuration. Show the default output with `$cmd = 'ffmpeg 2>&1';`