# Can't execute exec command (php / windows / ffmpeg)

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg, exec, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run this command that does work in cli

```
ffmpeg -i tmp1.flv -c:a copy -vf drawbox=:x=0:y=0:color=invert:t=2 output1.flv
```

I was able to run only `ffmpeg -version` by php.

```
$res = exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -version");
```

Location of `tmp1.flv` file:

```
C:\wamp\www\tmp1.flv
```

When I'm running `$res = exec("chdir")` => `C:\wamp\www\`

How can I run this by php

```
ffmpeg -i tmp1.flv -c:a copy -vf drawbox=:x=0:y=0:color=invert:t=2 output1.flv
```

I tried:

```
$res = exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i tmp1.flv -c:a copy -vf drawbox=:x=0:y=0:color=invert:t=2 output1.flv", $output, $return_var);
$res = exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i C:\\wamp\\www\\tmp1.flv -c:a copy -vf drawbox=:x=0:y=0:color=invert:t=2 C:\\wamp\\www\\output1.flv", $output, $return_var);
$res = exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i C:\wamp\www\tmp1.flv -c:a copy -vf drawbox=:x=0:y=0:color=invert:t=2 C:\wamp\www\output1.flv", $output, $return_var);
$res = exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i \"C:\wamp\www\tmp1.flv\" -c:a copy -vf drawbox=:x=0:y=0:color=invert:t=2 \"C:\wamp\www\output1.flv\"", $output, $return_var);
$res = exec("C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i 'C:\wamp\www\tmp1.flv' -c:a copy -vf drawbox=:x=0:y=0:color=invert:t=2 'C:\wamp\www\output1.flv'", $output, $return_var);
...
```

but `echo $res` and `echo $output` gives nothing, and `echo $return_var` gives 1

+++UPDATE+++

Made a little progress thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770173/php-ffmpeg-exec-returns-null?rq=1), it does give me output and info about the file, but still can't run the whole command.

```
$cmd = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i tmp1.flv 2>&1';

exec($cmd, $output, $value);

var_dump($output);
var_dump($value);
var_dump($cmd)
```

+++UPDATE 2+++

`echo exec('whoami')` => `nt authority\system`

Comment: "To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the output parameter. " ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: have you checked if the user who executes the script has write access to the output directory?

Comment: @steven thank you, I check it again & It says that I'm nt authority\system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had `ffmpeg` after `ffmpeg.exe` - that's why it didn't work.

```
$cmd = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i tmp1.flv -c:a copy  -vf drawbox=:x=0:y=0:color=invert:t=2 output2.flv 2>&1';
exec($cmd, $output)
```